# Exporting mutable values: import vs require

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to understand the difference between `import` and `require` when it comes to exporting / importing mutable values.

Imagine a file **a.ts**:

```
export let a = 1;
export function f() {
  a = 2;
}
```

Then three versions of a main file, **index1.ts**:

```
import { a, f } from "./a";

console.log(a); // 1
f();
console.log(a); // 2
```

**index2.ts**:

```
const { a, f } = require("./a");

console.log(a); // 1
f();
console.log(a); // 1
```

**index3.ts**:

```
const _ = require("./a");

console.log(_.a); // 1
_.f();
console.log(_.a); // 2
```

- I expected **index1.ts** to produce the same output as **index2.ts**, but it does not. The `import`ed `a` always references the actual `a` variable from **a.ts**. What are the guarantees that this will always be the case ? Does the spec force this behavior ?
- **index3.ts** works because the properties of the object returned by `require` are *getters*. Again, is this guaranteed to be always true ? Can we rely on it for the design of a library for example ?

Comment: `import` creates an alias, not a new variable. `const` does create a variable which takes a copy of the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identifiers imported with `import` can behave weirdly - they can seemingly reassign themselves on their own if the module that's exporting them reassigns what's exported, which is why

```
import { a, f } from './a';
console.log(a);
f()
console.log(a);
```

could indeed log 1, and then 2 - which is something you wouldn't see in any other sort of JavaScript.

> Does the spec force this behavior ?

Yes, it does.

Using `require` instead of `import`, on the other hand, returns the *namespace object* exported by the other module instead of creating the oddly-behaving module variables. This object works like you'd expect any other object in Javascript to - if you destructure the object's values into variables, those values won't "change on their own" unless you explicitly do something like `a = someOtherValue` in the current scope.

> index3.ts works because the properties of the object returned by require are getters. Again, is this guaranteed to be always true ? Can we rely on it for the design of a library for example ?

It's a bit more like the namespace object property values get reassigned when the module they're being exported reassigns them. If you have

```
// foo.ts
export let a = 1;
export function f() {
  a = 2;
}
```

then the namespace object imported elsewhere will be a *live* structure containing

```
{
  a: currentValueOfAInFoo,
  f: currentValueOfFInFoo,
}
```

That said, while it's *possible* to depend on this behavior, I'd highly recommend never writing code that relies on it, because it's quite strange compared to how one would normally expect an identifier to behave - it's potentially confusing for the code-readers and code-writer to have to consider.